# Responsive Web Design - Displaying Video on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, video

I have a simple question about responsive web design. Basically, I have this code which will run a video on computers:

```
<object width="480" height="360">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<embed src="FileLocationAndName.mp4" width="560" height="469" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain"
allowfullscreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
</object>
```

and this code which will run it on the iPad.

```
<video width="480" height="360" x-webkit-airplay="allow" controls="true"
autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="FileLocationAndName.mp4/playlist.m3u8" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

The code works correctly for each (I deleted the actual file locations out, so if it looks incorrect, that's why.) I just need each block to display on the appropriate machine and hide the opposite block on the page. Searching "responsive web design" is returning opinionated blogs on why RWD is either revolutionary or a complete waste of time.

I just need it to work. What do I need to include? Can I do it with CSS or something? display: none; or some such? (I don't want to write & maintain a second website.)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use media queries to detect the width of the browser. It is possible to use a media query to detect iPads (a quick Google search should show you how). Then, like you said, use `display: none;` on the things you want to hide. So, for example, add `class="desktop"` to your desktop video, and `class="ipad"` to your iPad video. In your iPad media query, you will have `.desktop { display: none; }`, and `.ipad { display: block; }`. Outside of the media query, you will have `.ipad { display: none; }` and `.desktop { display: block; }`. I hope this makes sense. You can also consider using a video plugin that works more universally, like [VideoJS](http://www.videojs.com/).